# ReactJs can I use more than one mixin in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mixins

Can I use more than one mixin in a react component?

Something like this:

```
var GeneralMessagePage = React.createClass({

mixins: [oneMixin],[anotherMixin]
```

Many thanks

Comment: As the attr is called `mixin's'`, you can use `mixins: [oneMixin, anotherMixin]`. Take a look at the doc : [React#mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins). __A nice feature of mixins is that if a component is using **multiple mixins** and several mixins define the same lifecycle method...__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
mixins: [oneMixin, anotherMixin,...]
```